# Modify cells of HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an HTML table which is styled using CSS. The table is composed of two rows, but the upper row only has need of 3 columns whereas the bottom row has 5 columns.

```
<table class="xp-flt-leg-sum" name="flightLegSummary">
    <tbody>
        <!--Row 1-->
        <tr class="xp-flt-ctyttl-fnt" name="from2City">
            <!--Col1 -->
            <td colspan="2" class="flightLegSummary xp-fl-md-lg"><span id="departureCity0">Seattle</span></td>
            <!--Col2 -->
            <td colspan="1" class="xp-fl-md-lg"><span id="arrivalCity0">New York</span></td>
            <!--Col3 -->
            <td colspan="2">
                <span id="connectingCity-0-0" class="xp-connecting-cities">
                    Charlotte                                         
                 </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="xp-flt-arptttl-fnt">
            <!--Col1 -->
            <td class="xp-flt-mdl-leg-col1 ">
                <span id="departureAirport0">SEA&nbsp;</span>
                <span id="departureTime0">
                    10:15pm
                </span>
            </td>
            <!--Col2 -->
            <td class="xp-flt-mdl-leg-colicn ">
                <span class="xp-flt-mdl-drctn-icn" id="directionIcon0"><!-- --></span>
            </td>
            <!--Col3 -->
            <td class="xp-flt-mdl-leg-col2 ">
                <span id="arrivalAirport0">LGA&nbsp;</span>
                <span id="arrivalTime0">
                    9:45am
                </span>
                <span style="display:inline-block;" id="addedDays">
                            +1&nbsp;Tag
                </span>
            </td>
            <!--Col4 -->
            <td class="xp-flt-mdl-leg-col3">
                <span class="xp-flt-leg-stop-span" id="flight0StopCount">
                    1&nbsp;Stopp
                </span>
            </td>
            <!--Col5 -->
            <td class="xp-flt-mdl-leg-col4">
                <span id="flightDuration0">8Std.&#8203;30Min.</span>
            </td>
       </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Below is the CSS controlling the table.

```
.xp-fl-md-lg {
    vertical-align: bottom !important;
}
.flightLegSummary {
    width: 111px;
}
#flightLegOutterCont .xp-flt-arptttl-fnt {
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 10px;
}

#flightModuleControl .xp-flt-mdl-leg-col1 {
    max-width: 52px;
    min-width: 52px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-top: 6px;
}

#flightModuleControl .xp-flt-mdl-leg-colicn {
    max-width: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    text-align: center;
}
#flightModuleControl .xp-flt-mdl-leg-col2 {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    width: 110px;
}

#flightModuleControl .xp-flt-mdl-leg-col3 {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 76px;
}
#flightModuleControl .xp-flt-mdl-leg-col4 {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    width: 54px;
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is that I want to modify all the following cells to be a certain width:

```
<Row1,Col1> 98px wide
<Row1,Col2> 130px wide
<Row2,Col1> 86px wide
<Row2,Col2> 12px wide
<Row2,Col3> 130px wide
<Row2,Col4> 76px wide
```

I've been struggling, and I can't seem to modify the rows to be the desired width. Also, I don't understand the role of colspan for the first row. When I remove however, it really screws up the positioning of the cells.

Comment: You want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/79wey/

Comment: @Kyle Undefined: That's what I'd like but doing <td width=...> doesn't seem to be working in my case.

Comment: Any chance you could use `DIV`'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colspan sets the number of columns a cell should span. Here you have 3 header cells, the first spanning 2 columns below it, the second spanning 1, and the third spanning 2 (adding up to five columns below the three header cells).

It looks like you want 3 cells on top and 4 columns below, correct? If so you need to make the 3rd header cell be colspan=1 and it will be 76px wide like the column below it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It might help you understand the functionality of colspan to add border="1" to the TABLE tag.  This will show you how column 1 of row 1 is being expanded to cover two of the columns of the row beneath it.  Sometimes having a visualization of the workings of it is better than a bunch of text-based explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I think Michelle clarified your table issue well, I would just add that based on your static layout of two rows with varying cell widths, have you considered using two simple rows of floating divs within a container? I think you'd have more flexibility and simpler code.